# Telecommuter tax burdens - California worker employed by a Pennsylvania company

Tags: taxes

I am a California resident working remotely for a Pennsylvania company. My bi-weekly pay stub shows withholdings for PA state unemployment insurance. I don't see any withholdings for either the California unemployment insurance or the California disability tax. Is it wrong that those are not being withdrawn, given that I do telecommute from my home in California?

Comment: I don't think it is wrong, but you will want to check out and understand the CA taxes you may owe.  You may be subject to the difference between CA and PA taxes.  If you pay Philly taxes as well that can be a factor.  You probably want professional advice at least the first time you file this way to avoid double taxation.

Answer (score 3):

A quick google shows that apparently it is not wrong.  Check out this [random link that I found](https://www.journalofaccountancy.com/issues/2009/jun/20091371.html) (My emphasis)

> But as it grows in feasibility and popularity, telecommuting across
>   state lines could subject your clients to some ugly income tax
>   surprises. New York state taxes all New York-source salary and wage
>   income of nonresident employees when the arrangement is for
>   convenience rather than by necessity (Laws of New York, § 601(e), 20
>   NYCRR 132.18). **Pennsylvania**, Nebraska, Delaware and New Jersey have
>   similar allocation laws, rules or policies. The rest of the states and
>   the District of Columbia either don’t tax wage or salary income or,
>   for nonresidents, allocate to themselves wage or salary income only
>   when it is paid for services performed within their borders (physical
>   presence).

I'd suggest your accountant would be the best person to ask about this.

---

Note that I am not a lawyer, nor did I stay in hotel last night, and this is not legal advice.